# Typescript incorrect assignment/mapping into strongly typed object

Tags: typescript

I have a raw object which I want to map/assign to a Typescript's typed object. When I do the assignment, its not as per the object type e.g.

```
interface TokenModel {
    username: string;
    password: string;
}

const obj = {
    usernam1: 'ali@mailinator.com',
    password: 'admin',
    extraProp: 'abc123'
};

const model: TokenModel = <TokenModel><any>obj;
```

Even I'm casting the raw object and assigning it to a typed object, the value of `model` becomes the same what has assigned like:

```
{
    usernam1: 'ali@mailinator.com',
    password: 'admin',
    extraProp: 'abc123'
}
```

Whether it should have the value like this:

```
{
    username: null,
    password: 'admin'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually "casting" it to the type, you're telling the compiler that the object *should* have those values. It won't assign null/undefined values to fields automatically.

EDIT:

answering the question in the comment:

```
const model: TokenModel = {
    username: obj.usernam1,
    password: obj.password
}
```

Comment: How to do the casting then, to achieve what I have mentioned?

Comment: You have to write it yourself. Reassign the values